# How to compare two values in formBuilder?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, mean-stack, angular-reactive-forms

I have the form builder as follows,

```
this.feedbackForm = new FormGroup({
  figure: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+$/)),
  maxVal: new FormControl(''),
  minVal: new FormControl('', Validators.max(feedbackForm.values.maxVal - 1)),
});
```

I want to compare minVal such that it is less than max value, but from the above code it shows the error as follows,

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing your form in your form definition. Meaning you're referencing `feedbackForm` before it is defined.

There are many ways to accomplish what you're going for. One way would be to add the validator to your form control after you define your form.

```
this.feedbackForm = new FormGroup({
  figure: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+$/)),
  mixVal: new FormControl(''),
  maxVal: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+$/)),
});


this.feedbackForm.get('minVal')
    .setValidators(Validators.max(this.feedbackForm.get('maxVal').value - 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

marcusshep mentioned there are several possible ways and provided a good one. I figured I'd add another. It might be overkill for what you want, though.

You could make it a form-level, custom validator.

```
static minLessThanMax(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
    const value: formValue = (control as FormGroup).getRawValue();
    if (value) {
        const minValue = formValue.minValue;
        const maxValue = formValue.maxValue;

        if (minValue > maxValue) {
            control.get('min').setErrors({ minMoreThanMax: true });
        } else {
            control.get('end').setErrors(null);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then when you new up your FormGroup:

```
this.feedbackForm = new FormGroup({
  figure: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+$/)),
  mixVal: new FormControl(''),
  maxVal: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+$/)),
}, { validator: minLessThanMax });
```